# how to bundle a module/component to js and use in another angular project?

Tags: javascript, angular, bundling-and-minification

I was just trying to build a module/component and serve it as a JS bundle. it builds:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component-overview',
  template: '<button><ng-content></ng-content></button>',
})
export class ButtonComponent {}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ButtonComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

the issue is that after building it to a javascript bundle. when I try to import it in another angular project. I get:

```
//ERROR in ... error TS2306 '...' is not a module.
   loadChildren: () => import('...').then(m=>m.ButtonModule)
```

maybe I am missing the point here and things are different in angular, having webpack control makes it a lot easier but I want to avoid bringing custom builders and fiddling with the settings as little as possible.

Question is, is there a well documented way to bundle a module or even a standalone component to be used outside my project as a JS bundle? I could not find anything useful other than high level explanation of reusing and lazyloading thing already inside the same project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours browsing around. I figured it out.

The answer that @json-derulo gave is part of the solution but there are more steps to make this work.

1. follow the guide: https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries
   here is the tricky part if you import the lib inside the workspace it will work. but that does not make much sense. You likely have another repository with a angular app that you want to consume the lib.
2. now to be able to import the this component as a lazy loaded route you will need to add "@angular/router" to the lib peerDependecies and run npm install again
3. now create a routing module and add the empty path to point to the component in the lib.

```
//my-lib-routing.module.ts
import { NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { MyLibComponent } from "./my-lib.component";

const routes= [
 { path: '', component: MyLibComponent },
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   RouterModule.forChild(
     routes,
   )
   // other imports here
 ],
 // providers: [RouterModule],
 exports: [RouterModule]

})
export class myLibRoutingModule { }
```

4. change the libmodule to import the routing module

```
//
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { myLibRoutingModule } from './my-lib-routing.module';
import { MyLibComponent } from './my-lib.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [MyLibComponent],
  imports: [
    myLibRoutingModule
  ],
})
export class MyLibModule { }
```

5. on the lib project root run 'npm run build'.
6. create a separate repo and "ng new app"
7. add the lib to the package.json of the main app, something like "my-lib": "../my-lib-ws/dist/my-lib".
8. open angular.json and add "preserveSymlinks": true to the build options.
9. run npm i to link the lib as a dependency.
10. add the libmoudle as a lazy loaded route

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
 {path: 'test', loadChildren: () => import('my-lib').then(m=>m.MyLibModule)}
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

11. run npm run start. and try to access the 'test' route. you should see the component loaded in the main app router outled

Now, this is more of learning exercise the bundles almost gets doubled. and you would profit more using module federation. But it is a use case we have. Anyhow the steps are here if anyone can't reproduce let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are building this module as part of an *application* which is supposed to run in a browser. But what you are looking for is to build this module as part of a *library* which can be re-used in other projects.

See this official Angular guide on [how to create a library](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries).

Comment: I tried that, getting a different error: "ERROR: in  ... Can't import the named export ... from ecmaSCript module (only default export is available)" I tried using the default export as well but it does not work either, I guessing the version needs to be pre 13 to work with angular 9

Comment: I followed their docs and the module loads, no errors, but nothing happens... do you have any example? I only found importing module that are not bundled and from the same repo. That is not really helpful as I am trying to build the library and use the bundled module.